# Custom MKAnnotation always says it's an MKUserLocation class

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a custom class called `Device` which implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol. In the examples I'm following (MapKit and Core Location on the iPad from O'Reilly Media), they say to check if the annotation I want to add is an `MKUserLocation` class and return nil if it is. I fully understand what that does, but the problem is that my `Device` class is always identified as `MKUserLocation` so it always returns nil so I never get any annotations added to the map. I've gone over the code again and again and again. I've the O'Reilly code samples as well and I can't see where I'm going off. It's really frustrating.

Here's my `Device.m`:

```
@implementation Device

@synthesize udId, user, latitude, longitude;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D internalCoordinate;

    internalCoordinate.latitude = [self.latitude doubleValue];
    internalCoordinate.longitude = [self.longitude doubleValue];

    return internalCoordinate;
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return self.user;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return nil;
}

- (id)initWithUDId:(NSString *)_udId User:(NSString *)_user Latitude:(NSNumber *)_latitude Longitude:(NSNumber *)_longitude {
    if (self == [super init]) {
        self.udId = _udId;
        self.user = _user;
        self.latitude = _latitude;
        self.longitude = _longitude;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [udId release];
    self.udId = nil;

    [user release];
    self.user = nil;

    [latitude release];
    self.latitude = nil;

    [longitude release];
    self.longitude = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And here's my `DeviceMapAnnotator.m`:

```
@implementation DeviceMapAnnotator

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        NSLog(@"annotation is an MKUserLocation class");

        return nil;
    }

    MKPinAnnotationView *deviceAnnotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"DeviceAnnotation"];

    if (deviceAnnotationView == nil) {
        deviceAnnotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"DeviceAnnotation"] autorelease];
        deviceAnnotationView.animatesDrop = NO;
        deviceAnnotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    }

    return deviceAnnotationView;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And here's the code calling it from my `DashboardViewController.m`:

```
- (void)updateMapAnnotations:(NSArray *)devices {
    for (Device *device in devices) {
        [map addAnnotation:device];
    }
}
```

And here's the code calling `updateMapAnnotations` from my app delegate:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    if (![request error]) {
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithJSONString:[request responseString] error:&jsonError];

        if (!jsonError || ([[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Success"] intValue] == 1)) {
            NSArray *jsonDevicesArray = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Devices"];
            NSMutableArray *devicesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[jsonDevicesArray count]];

            for (NSDictionary *deviceDictionary in jsonDevicesArray) {
                [devicesArray addObject:[[[Device alloc] initWithUDId:[deviceDictionary objectForKey:@"UDId"] User:[deviceDictionary objectForKey:@"User"] Latitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[deviceDictionary objectForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue]] Longitude:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[deviceDictionary objectForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]]] autorelease]];
            }

            [dashboardViewController updateMapAnnotations:devicesArray];
        } else {
            //  AUTHORIZATION FAILED
        }
    }
}
```

I basically make a call to the server every 45 seconds, get a list of devices and their locations as a JSON string which is then deserialized into an `NSArray` containing `Device` objects. I then pass the array to `updateMapAnnotations` which then loops it and calls `addAnnotation`. The whole process works, and I guarantee that the objects being sent to `DeviceMapAnnotator` are of type `Device`, however the `MKUserLocation` check always returns prematurely and the whole process is just stopped dead in the water.

I would really appreciate it if someone who knows what they're doing with iOS/Objective-C, etc, can help me out (that's pretty much everyone because I apparently am an idiot).

Just to vent, I must say that Objective-C is getting on my $hit list really fast.

Comment: Not sure if it's the cause but in initWithUDId, `if (self == [super init])` should be `if (self = [super init])`.  If you put `NSLog(@"ann=%@", annotation);` as the first line in viewForAnnotation, does it show your Device annotations?  Separately, for readability, maintainability and to make debugging easier, you should break up the really long `devicesArray addObject` line into multiple statements.

Comment: Sadly, fixing the conditional doesn't seem to have an effect. NSLog keeps saying that it's `MKUserLocation`...

Comment: So the log shows one <MKUserLocation> for each Device you have added?  How many device annotations are being added?  If showsUserLocation is turned on, turn it off to see the effect.  Show the Device interface (.h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work, although I don't know exactly what the solution was. In the end I scrapped everything and rewrote it from scratch in a new file and it worked at that point. I also realized that I was not sending back the latitude and logitude in the JSON, however that still wasn't the problem because they would be initialized as 0.0 anyway. In the end I have no idea what *really* fixed it, but it works, so I'll take it.

Sorry to waste your guys' time. :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not immediately seeing any problem with your code either. However, instead of initially testing to see if the annotation is an `MKUserLocation`, you could instead not test for that directly and test whether the annotation is a `Device`, like so:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Device class]]) {    
        MKPinAnnotationView *deviceAnnotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"DeviceAnnotation"];

        if (deviceAnnotationView == nil) {
             deviceAnnotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"DeviceAnnotation"] autorelease];
             deviceAnnotationView.animatesDrop = NO;
             deviceAnnotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        }

        return deviceAnnotationView;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"annotation is not a Device");

        return nil;
    }
}
```

This might not be a very helpful suggestion since it does basically the same thing, but maybe doing it a slightly different way will yield a different result when debugging and lead to the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  Apparently removing the annotations from the mapView causes some issues with how they are released.  Commenting out the code fixed it.

```
- (void)dealloc {

//[mapView removeAnnotations:mapView.annotations];  

[super dealloc];
```

}